# Memcache is not working on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to implement memcache on Codeigniter and but I am getting error "Invalid driver requested: CI_Cache_". Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/tomschlick/memcached-library this is the complete implementation for memcache in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Further information and some examples are required, but firstly make sure the `application/cache` directory is created and writeable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have an issue with your configurations. Notice the message: it is looking for `CI_Cache_` instead of the full name of the driver which is probably something like `CI_Cache_Memcache`. [You might want to review the documentation on cache](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Change your cache folder permission to 777, if youre on ubuntu try running from terminal - sudo chmod 777 /yourcachepath/. Or you can right click the folder and set the permission.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR install the memcached extension for PHP or provide a backup driver that is supported.

Make Sure you have the memcached extension loaded for PHP, if it its not loaded and a backup driver is not provided such as in  `$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));`, that "CI_Cache_" weird name is thrown since it passes NULL to the
`CI_Driver_Library, __get()` method, it happened to me because I din't have the memcached PHP extension installed, and CI  checks if its supported just before returning the caching object, then defaults to the backup, so install the extension or provide a backup driver that is supported